# Filter out duplicates from a JSON array

Tags: json, typescript

Lets say I have a JSON file with an array in it like this:

```
[
   {
    "distinct_id": "abc",
    "properties": {
      "bookID": "123",
      "userID": "abc",
    }
  },
  {
    "distinct_id": "abc",
    "properties": {
      "bookID": "123",
      "userID": "abc",
    }
  },
  {
    "distinct_id": "ced",
    "properties": {
      "bookID": "123",
      "userID": "ced",
    }
  },
  {
    "distinct_id": "abc",
    "properties": {
      "bookID": "456",
      "userID": "ced",
    }
  }
]
```

I am trying to figure out how I would loop through this and return a new array just one instance of each `distinct_id` (basically removing duplicates) - think of it like a an array of unique users.

I am using TypeScript. I was trying to use `Set` but that wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Item {
  distinct_id: string;
  properties: {
    bookID: string;
    userID: string;
  };
}

const getDistinctIds = (data: Item[]) => data.map(item => item.distinct_id);

const getUniqueDistinctIds = (data: Item[]) => Array.from(new Set(getDistinctIds(data)));

const getItemByDistinctId = (data: Item[], distinct_id: string) => data.find(item => item.distinct_id === distinct_id);

const getUniqueItems = (data: Item[]) => getUniqueDistinctIds(data).map(distinct_id => getItemByDistinctId(data, distinct_id));

const data: Item[] = [
  {
    "distinct_id": "abc",
    "properties": {
      "bookID": "123",
      "userID": "abc",
    }
  },
  {
    "distinct_id": "abc",
    "properties": {
      "bookID": "123",
      "userID": "abc",
    }
  },
  {
    "distinct_id": "ced",
    "properties": {
      "bookID": "123",
      "userID": "ced",
    }
  },
  {
    "distinct_id": "abc",
    "properties": {
      "bookID": "456",
      "userID": "ced",
    }
  }
];

const uniqueItems = getUniqueItems(data);
console.log(uniqueItems);
```

Here is link to [TS PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnIAmwAzmKAmAPrCEBcyZUoA5gNz7IAOUA9l9HIQSDPAQIAjXrwDWqACIMmrDuOQBXEtAVKwzEO04BfDkdy4EvEGWQsIYeaXIhKqQiWQBeZAApCcMDgGdAgMAG0AXQBKLwA+IgC4ADoMOC4fYEw45EzQpOIyCmpaKI4LKxs7MABVEGAAR3UIR0KXMDcPbz9E4MxImM94gEEoKDgATySYPgwfEAgAd2QAZXsfKpbnV3duwKj9sstrMFt7EIwAIXHNorcvX39A3tDIgBoiJyKaekY9VgH4o9kjBQIQMllBjlMPlPm1vl5PN4CltioRSuYjpV7LUGk1zp0Hj00H1otkqjjGs1YdsSLs4FEUmk-NTUWSzpgrjc2m46e9kV8SujyscEk9iS8IvcwpwxOIAET8uG0OUMOVwCQIOWvTgEOU8fiCYDCFU4HXyqSyBQmuUARgATABmLVm3WabTya3qzXatRmAhGH2mtQKlnfT0a53B-UCKBCEgm2XBi1yD2q+1OwPBt1QK2qr2R8R+5ABmVmkOtShh1VIQgF3XRw3G0Qu5By5O51vpuvy7MduU17tFksEROtxWV5V5iOZ1sN2NG+PNtS69up1sAFgArAA2buurQ5tf9iC1mdD3ARQ4VE7qOqU-H3cl3vGYWlA9GY3gAGwgSS-vBYHxb1xCB8XRIA)